# How to use excel formula to search cell that contain keyword, and return the corresponding value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a column in an excel sheet that contains all the logged issue descriptions.

The column is as such:

[image]
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIVGC.png)

I would like to create another reference sheet to categorise the issues based on the keyword.

E.g. of the ref sheet

[image]
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMTaj.png)

Which excel formula should I use for this logic - if the description column contains the keyword text, return the category.

Was thinking of using if......=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(.....   , combining with vlookup.  but unable to get it.

Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: note - the e.g. table is in the link

Comment: We don't go to off-site locations to get information needed for your question. All relevant content must be here, in the question itself. Please provide a text representation of your data. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: If you have `Excel 365` then can try `Filter()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a non-array-version would be:

```
=INDEX($B$7:$B$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$1:$B$4))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$7:$A$10,B1))),1))
```

another solution would be this **ARRAY-FORMULA: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER:**

```
=INDEX($B$6:$B$9,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$6:$A$9,B1)),ROW($B$1:$B$4)),1))
```

[image]

It just gives the first found keyword.

EDIT:
`AGGREGATE` can imitate several excel-functions, in this case `15` means `SMALL`. The `6` tells the function to ignore errors. This can be used to filter the list of found keywords. Basically it is linenumbers divided by positions of the keyword in the cell. For the first cell we get

```
  [1,2,3,4] / isnumber([9,#VAL!,#VAL!,#VAL!]) 
= [1,2,3,4] / [1,0,0,0]
= [1,#VAL!,#VAL!,#VAL!]
```

The errors get ignored and you get row 1 as result, which can be used in `INDEX`.

Comment: Thanks. the non-array solution works.  May i know what's the meaning for 15,6 in the aggregate formula?

Comment: @Jamie Tan see edit